# Search and sorts error logs based on a particular string

Tags: text-processing, logs, sort

1. How to search through all the errors.zip as well as from errors.log files filter by "Error" string and sort by date?
2. What about totals of errors?

requirement : here are 3 components are installed in my Linux server such as comp1,comp2 and comp3 . Each component has there own logs directory . Each logs directory contains below files 
Exception.log
connection.log 
comp1.log 
as well as few *.zip files . I want to search them , order them based on date along with need to show the total number of error count.

### error logs

2015-05-15 05:59:03,316 | 73002 | ERROR | JomaManagerThread RUNNING | Error clearing alarms to JOMA

Please let me know for additional information

Comment: Please provide example of your logs

Comment: 2015-05-15 05:59:03,316 | 73002 | ERROR | JomaManagerThread RUNNING | Error clearing alarms to JOMA

Comment: You can try something like: for i in `ls *.zip`; do unzip $i - |grep ERROR >>output; done; sort output >sorted_output

Comment: what about the .log files.

Comment: Check the answer of Anthon

Comment: @RomeoNinov I think you missed the `cat *.log` when proposing your [suggested edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/90736) ;-)

Comment: Yes, @Anthon :) And I usually prefer more visual style of structuring shell :) This is the reason I offer dedicated lines for *.log and sort

Comment: @RomeoNinov I agree it tends to get messy rather quickly

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't seem to need the filenames you can use `-p` to output the content
of the zip files:

```
(for i in ./*.zip; do unzip -p "$i"; done; cat ./*.log) |
   grep -F ERROR | sort
```

or if the files errors.zip are all over the place:

```
(find . -type f -name "*.zip" -exec unzip -p {} \;
 find . -type f -name "err*.log" -exec cat {} + ) |
   grep -F ERROR | sort
```

This does away with the zip file name and the particular content file name that unzip extracts, as well as the log file name. If you need that info I would write a python program for the task, that inserts the filename somewhere in each of the lines found (not before the date of course). You can use the standard `zipfile` module to process the contents of a zipfile without first extracting the files and have the program write to stdout for piping into `sort`

Comment: thanks for the reply Anthon . If i want to add multiple directory to this for loop shall it work .

Comment: @user112232 yes you either do a `*.zip */*.zip` etc if the levels of subdirectories is limited, or else use `find . -name "*.zip" -exec unzip -p {} \;"` if the files are burried deep. For the logs the same applies.

Comment: i wrote the below command 
(for i in find . -name "*.zip" -exec unzip -p {} \; do unzip -p "$i"; done; cat "*.log") | grep -F ERROR| sort

but getting this error "-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `done' "

Comment: @user112232 I updated my answer. Next time please be more specific about details like the fact that you have no idea where the errors.zip files might be on the filesystem that makes it more easy to get the answers right.

Comment: Anthon , sorry for the inconvenience . let me clear my problem . There are 3 components are installed in my Linux server such as comp1,comp2 and comp3 . Each component has there own logs directory  . each logs directory contains below files Exception.log,connection.log and comp1.log as well as few *.zip files . I want to search them , order them based on date along with need to show the total number of error count. Please let me know if you want some additional information.

Comment: @user112232 I was going to suggest that you edit your post, but with the requirement of not just parsing `errors.zip` but also that you need a total error count this makes it a different question altogether, requiring a new question as an edit of that magnitude would invalidate my answer.  For the error count combined with sorted output use `tee` (or post  a new question on how to do that).

Comment: Anthon , i am executing this script from the root directory getting this error                                                                                     ssrun@EMFX4250-04:~> (find . -type f -name "*.gz" -exec unzip -p {} \; find . -type f -name "*.log" -exec cat {} + ) | grep -F ERROR | sort
find: paths must precede expression: find
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]

Comment: thank you all for the support . Above solution solved my problem.

Comment: @user112232 Then please consider to accept it by checking the V sign under the vote count of this answer. That is the normal way to indicate the (best) solution to your problem.